# QGIS python - get units of the raster

Tags: python, gdal, qgis

In QGIS with pyQgis I would like to determine if input raster has units in degrees or metres. 
[Here](https://www.gislite.com/tutorial/k8022) I learned I can get projection from raster using GDAL:

```
inRaster = gdal.Open(rasterInPath,GA_ReadOnly)
projRef = inRaster.GetProjection()
print(projRef)
```

what's gives me string for raster with EPSG 4326:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

and for raster with EPSG 3857:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
```

I guess I can do:

```
isInMetres = "PROJCS" in projRef
```

But is there any other solution? I don't consider this very readable and not sure if I can cover all corner cases this way (e.g. missing projRef). Dont need to be necessary with GDAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **PyQgis API** you can use the `mapUnits` method of [`QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html) objects. It returns a `QgsUnitTypes.DistanceUnit` value, so you can use it like that for example :

```py
# lyr is a QgsRasterLayer
crs = lyr.crs()
# crs is a QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem 
unit = crs.mapUnits()
print('Unit is {}'.format(QgsUnitTypes.toString(unit)))
# 'Unit is mètres' (i'm using french language)
```

Reusing your code, you can write:

```
isInMetres = crs.mapUnits() == 0
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Thank you mgc.

Comment: I would love to vote for the answer but I am below 15 reputation points.-(